# Change URL of ?q=user

Tags: users, uri

By default, Drupal uses `site.com/?q=user` or with clean URLs enabled, `site.com/user` to display the user login page. However, that is conflicting with my hosting provider's own rewrite settings, where navigating to that link brings up the actual web server admin login. Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your hosting provides default cpanel url is `/admin`

In that case you need [Rename Admin Paths](http://drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths) module.

**The purpose of this module is to secure drupal backend by overriding admin path.**

**Overview**

This module allows you to:

rename path like '/admin/...' to '/something/...'

rename path like '/user/..' to '/something else/..'

Answer (score 0):

Give the page an alias using the built-in Path module.

Comment: Path redirect perhaps is required here instead of alias to ensure others wont hit admin screen provided owner has some other means to access admin screen else all will be locked out.